# Holding temp data in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I have a list of products, same products have different size, colors, quantity amount, price which varies independently on size, colour etc so, instead of posting something back to server on every value change such as size or colour, can't we store table on html which has all the variation for that particular product. I know we can use ajax post but its again posting something back to server. Is there some efficient way of storing data in stateless http or browser??

Comment: You can use data() - http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have been using data attr with display none style however is this fine??

Comment: As long as you can still get to the data, yes.

Comment: Its working fine but still I am wondering some other possible solutions if any, I am having data more like on table form with column name preceding with data

Comment: This should help you - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Comment: thanks for the link, however I was worried about browser support and key value won't help in my case coz price now depends on data-color, data-size and data-model i.e. multiple keys

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54058/discussion-between-brykneval-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: I cannot go to chat from this computer.

Comment: Have you tried cookies?